# How to Merge a 4 * 4 matrix into 2 *2

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Dashboard designed in `tableau` having a 4 * 4 structure look like a 4 * 4 matrix how can i merge 2 cells to make it a 2 * 2 ?

[image]

some thing like above,

now i need like this !

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I am having a hard time understanding what you want from this question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, but I still do not see what you mean by merging. If you want to get rid of a variable (like "Very high"), right click on it and select "exclude".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct,then you are trying to **group** (*i guess*)

like very low+low into low and Very high+high =high ?

You could do this

click the columns you want to group : then right click --> group

similarly you could do for the rows as well ! (choose rows and then click group)

it should give you a 2 * 2 !

Comment: con you please put some example of how to do this ! sounds right answer to me,i'll try this !

Comment: you need a example? y no you try some ? just `click the coulmn you wnna group by this even a 8 * 8 look like table be a 4*4 or 2 *2